# Swift pass through clicks in a child view controller

Tags: swift

```
class PassThroughView: UIView {
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        for subview in subviews {
            if !subview.isHidden && subview.isUserInteractionEnabled && subview.point(inside: convert(point, to: subview), with: event) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

I have a child view controller that takes up about 30% of the bottom space of my screen. This child view controller manages a few floating buttons.

When user presses on the blank transparent regions between the floating buttons, touches are received by the child view controller and it is possible that there is a UIButton BEHIND the child view controller that the user wanted to touch, but cannot touch it because it is covered by the "transparent" region of the child view controller.

I found some discussion about subclassing UIView and override the point inside function as above, but how to do this when i have a child view controller?

p/s: Added a screenshot below to illustrate the problem. The child view controller manages 4 floating buttons. The child view controller has a default view and I set it to yellow color to be obvious. The blue information button is an example of a UIButton that is on the main view controller, covered by this view of the childviewcontroller.

[image]

p/s2: This is how the child view controller is added to main view:

```
private func createControlBar(){
    controlBarViewController = ControlBarViewController()
    controlBarViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(controlBarViewController.view)
    controlBarViewController.delegate = self

    controlBarViewController.view.snp.makeConstraints { m in
        m.bottom.equalTo(view.snp.bottom)
        m.centerX.equalTo(view.snp.centerX)
        m.width.equalTo(view.snp.width)
        m.height.equalTo(180)
    }
}
```

Where should I subclass the UIView?

Comment: “touches are received by the child view controller” Really? How? View controllers do not normally receive touches. Show us what you’re doing.

Comment: @matt I meant touches are received by the default view of the child view controller

Comment: @matt added a screenshot

Comment: Make the controller small enough to cover only the 4 buttons. If there is some dimming overlay, make it a separate view with user interaction disabled. That's all you need. By the way, this kind of architecture is a bit strange. Overlays are usually implemented using container controllers, not child controllers (e.g. `UITabbarController`, `UINavigationController`).

Comment: I noticed the addChild is a mistake, the key is view.addSubview(controlBarViewController.view) which added the key view managed by controlBarViewController. My question is how to subclass this view into Passthroughview?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my problem is completely resolved as long as shift all codes from CustomBarViewController to CustomBarView. I don't really need a view control, all I need is a custom view that overrides the point inside point method

```
private func createControlBar(){

    controlBarView = ControlBarView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
    controlBarView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(controlBarView)

    controlBarView.snp.makeConstraints { m in
        m.bottom.equalTo(view.snp.bottom)
        m.centerX.equalTo(view.snp.centerX)
        m.width.equalTo(view.snp.width)
        m.height.equalTo(180)
    }
}
```

Inside ControlBarView.....

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    for subview in subviews {
        if !subview.isHidden && subview.isUserInteractionEnabled && subview.point(inside: convert(point, to: subview), with: event) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```